# Determine If PostGIS Geometry Is a Circle

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a PostGIS database table that contains several generic geometries in one of it's columns. Sometimes I have geometries that are intended to be circles which I insert into the database as the result of a center point and a radius point using something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (drawing) 
VALUES (
    ST_Buffer(
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0)::geography, 
        (SELECT 
            ST_Distance(
                ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(0 0)'), 
                ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(1 0)')
                )
            )
        )::geometry
    )
```

Now I would like to query the table for all the values inserted in this way, using something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTABLE WHERE FUNCTION_SAYS_GEOMETRY_IS_CIRCLE(geometry)
```

Does anybody have a recommendation? If this involves inserting my data differently that is okay. I have thought about adding an extra column for "is_circle" or something but that feels like a hack. I would prefer some insight from the geometry itself.

Comment: Calculating the area/perimeter ratio might actually be more expensive than adding a char(1) column.

Comment: Buffers are not perfect circles but only a more or less rough approximation. Also beware of the projection you use (a circle of 1 degree is not a circle if measured in meters.) That being said, the approach from @OClark could be complemented by a filtering on the shape bounding box X to Y ratio (should be close to a square)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try calculating a compactness score for your geometries to see if they are a circle. Something like the Polsby-Popper test will calculate a ratio between 1 and 0, 1 being a perfect circle and any other geometric shape will have a smaller ratio.

4 * pi() * (area/(perimeter^2))

If you are working with perfect circles you can select anything with a ratio of 1.

Here is a blog post on calculating the compactness of congressional districts in PostGIS where they use a few compactness tests one of which is the Polsby-Popper.

https://www.azavea.com/blog/2016/07/11/measuring-district-compactness-postgis/

Comment: As @Vince points out, incorporating this alongside an isCircle field would save a lot of processing. I would look at putting this function into a trigger to automatically update the isCircle field after an individual row is inserted or updated.

Comment: Keep in mind that `ST_Buffer` does not create true circles. Most "circles" in GIS will actually be a many-sided polygon, and `ST_Buffer` defaults to creating a 32-sided regular polygon. (Though PostGIS does support circular arcs, using it is still pretty niche.) The Polsby-Popper score will be 0.996785…

Answer (score 4):

You ***can*** compute a compactness test in a query, but you really don't want to.  Here's an example of a small (100k row) table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example1
;

CREATE TABLE example1 (
    idcol       serial      NOT NULL,
    isCircle    char(1)         NULL,
    geomcol     geometry        NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  example1_pk PRIMARY KEY (idcol),
    CONSTRAINT  enforce_srid CHECK (st_srid(geomcol) = 4326)
)
with (
    OIDS=FALSE
);

INSERT INTO example1(isCircle,geomcol)
SELECT isCircle, (CASE WHEN isCircle = 'Y'
        THEN ST_Buffer(point::geography,km*1000)::geometry
        ELSE ST_Envelope(ST_Buffer(point::geography,km*1000)::geometry)::geometry
        END) as geomcol
FROM (
    SELECT  ST_SetSRID(
        ST_MakePoint(
        (random()*360.0) - 180.0,
        (acos(1.0 - 2.0 * random()) * 2.0 - pi()) * 90.0 / pi()),
        4326) as point,
        (CASE WHEN random() > 0.4 THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END)::char(1) as isCircle,
        floor(random()*50 + 50) as km
    FROM  generate_series(1, 100000) vtab
) vt ;
-- 100000 rows affected, 28.5 secs execution time.

CREATE INDEX example1_spx ON example1 USING GIST (geomcol);
CREATE INDEX example1_ix1 ON example1(isCircle);

-- Query time

SELECT count(*) FROM example1 
WHERE isCircle = 'Y';
-- 60174 rows in 30ms

SELECT count(*) FROM example1 
WHERE 4 * pi() * (ST_Area(geography(geomcol),true) / (ST_Perimeter(geography(geomcol),true) * ST_Perimeter(geography(geomcol),true))) > 0.99;
-- 60174 rows in 18300ms
```

Computing the isCircle property **once** per geometry is going to represent a significant savings vice computing it with each query, even if you aren't working in geodetic space.  This isn't a hack, just good SQL practice.

---

Addendum: As noted in @JGH's comment below, you can reduce the cost of the geodetic area and perimeter calculation by creating a function and a covering index on that function.

It's also faster to use the `pow` function to square the perimeter value (at least on my PG 9.5 instance), and using that also drops the index query to effectively identical (140ms down to 32ms)

```
CREATE FUNCTION compactness( geometry ) RETURNS double precision AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN 4.0 * pi() * (ST_Area( $1 ::geography,true) / 
                     pow(ST_Perimeter( $1 ::geography,true),2.0));
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

CREATE INDEX example1_cx1 on example1(compactness(geomcol));
-- 12100ms (due to pow() function)

SELECT count(*) FROM example1 where compactness(geomcol) > 0.99;
--    32ms
```

Still, if you have the `isCircle` value up-front, it's not a hack to use it (and if it gets corrupted, you can use the compactness function to recover).

Comment: Turning the equation into a function and creating an index on it `CREATE INDEX example1_ix2 ON example1(compactness(geomcol));` would get the same benefit, while allowing playing with the threshold value (`SELECT count(*) FROM example1 WHERE compactness(geomcol) > 0.99;`) and not having to handle an extra column (that would eventually be updated to a wrong value by someone, one day)

Comment: Not exactly the same benefit, since the Y/null index is going to be faster than the `double precision` covering index (30ms v. 140ms), and you have to pay that function execution cost build the index at some point(s), even if it isn't on every query.