# Select circular polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector

I have a multipolygon layer, in which some geometries are circles, drawn in an unknown GIS. How can I select only those features which are circular? A quick manual check confirms that circular features do not all have the same number of points/vertices.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329610/determine-if-postgis-geometry-is-a-circle

Comment: Just to make a warning: Circles on the sphere, ellipsoid or projection plane?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the field calculator in order to check whether the `minimal circle` differs much from the actual shape, e.g. by calculating the `$area`.

`if(area(minimal_circle($geometry))<$area*1.05,1,0)`

This checks, whether the the area of the minimal circle is smaller than the area of the original geometry times 1.05 (5 % tolerance accounting for different number of vertices) and will select the geometry, if this is the case.

Comment: Am I right that this works for single-part, but not multiparts? I guess `minimal_circle()` is for the whole feature, not the parts. I'll see if I can handle taht in the expression as well.

Comment: The minimal circle computation is probably a bit expensive to compute - use the ratio of perimeter to area and the fact that a circle has the maximal perimeter:area ratio of any shape. Features with more than one ring can't be circles so filter those out first?

Answer (score 4):

[The isoperimetric quotient](https://www.nctm.org/tmf/library/drmath/view/55445.html) of a circle in a plane equals 1.  You could [explode your multipart features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/exploding-multipart-polygons-within-shapefile-in-qgis).  Add a new attribute and [calculate the area](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-calculating-an-area) of your polygons.  Add a new attribute and [calculate the perimeter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30006/how-to-calculate-polygon-areas-and-perimeters-using-qgis) of the polygons. Then use the field calculator to generate the IQ of the polygons in the attribute table using this formula:

```
Q = 4 pi A / P^2
```

For shapefiles the polygons will never be perfect circles since each will be using points to define the shapes of the polygons but the polygons with IQs closer to 1 will be  circles.